# Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input - Get request fetch

Tags: reactjs, flask, fetch

I have been successful in sending data back to the flask server with a post request. However I am now trying fetch that data and display it in my console log. I am currently getting a unhandled rejection error: unexpected end of JSON input and not too sure what is wrong.

Error:
Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input

App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Form from './components/Form'
import './App.css';


function App() {
  const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState ([{}])

  useEffect(()=> {

    fetch('/api').then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(data => console.log(data))
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app)

@app.route('/api', methods=['GET','POST'])
def api():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        email = request.form['email']
        occupation = request.form['occupation']
        print('Username: ' + username + ' Email: ' + email + ' occupation: ' + occupation) 
        print('Json ', (jsonify(username)))
        return username 
    else:
        return ''
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not returning a JSON response from the server. You are returning the `username`, which doesn't look like valid JSON.

If you look at [the Flask docs about JSON](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#apis-with-json), it shows two main ways to send a JSON response.

For your use case, it seems you could change the return statement in the `app()` function in `App.py` to the following:

```
return {
    "username": username
}
```

Comment: Oh cool, if I use the Jsonify() would it do the same thing? Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting an unexpected token in the console log atm too.

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0